# Primefaces Datagrid is working but popup is empty

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

Why my popup is empty . image is coming but data is not coming ..

```
<p:dataGrid var="publicationVar" value="#{adminhome.lazyModel}"
            columns="5" id="imageGridId" lazy="true" rows="15" paginator="true"
            style="float: left;" binding="#{adminhome.dataGrid}"
            emptyMessage="Records non trovati!"
            paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
            rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" paginatorPosition="bottom"
            rendered="#{adminhome.renderImages}">
            <p:column id="colGridId">
                <p:panel style="width: 50%;" id="panlId">
                    <h:panelGrid id="panGridId">
                        <p:commandLink oncomplete="dlg2.show()" update=":form:tesss"
                            process="@this" id="comLinkId">
                            <p:graphicImage id="grapImgId"
                                value="#{publicationVar.imageTmbPath}" width="140" height="160"
                                style="margin-right: -12px" alt="#{publicationVar.ISSNcode}"
                                title="#{publicationVar.editore}, #{publicationVar.title}, &#8364; #{publicationVar.priceStr}" />
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{publicationVar}"
                                target="#{adminhome.selectedPubblicazioni}" id="setPropId" />
                        </p:commandLink>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:panel>
            </p:column>
</p:dataGrid>
```

Here is the dialog box .  I can see blank dialog .But it was working before the lazy concept is introduced .

```
       <p:dialog id="modalDialog" widgetVar="dlg2" modal="true" height="100%"  dynamic="true">
          <p:outputPanel id="tesss">
            <p:panelGrid>
              <p:row>
                <p:column rowspan="13" >
                  <div style="width:100%;height:100%">
                    <h:commandLink  action="popup.xhtml" target="_blank" >
                      <p:graphicImage style="margin-left:5px" value="#{adminhome.selectedPubblicazioni.imagePath}" height="500" width="375" />
                    </h:commandLink>
                  </div>
                </p:column>  
                </p:row>

              <p:row> <p:column> <h:outputText value="Data " style="float: left;margin-left: 30px;color:red;font-size: 18px;font-weight: bold"/>    </p:column> <p:column> <h:outputText value="#{adminhome.selectedPubblicazioni.sample}" style="float: left;"/>   </p:column>    </p:row>
              <p:row> <p:column> <h:outputText value="Name " style="float: left;margin-left: 30px;color:red;font-size: 18px;font-weight: bold"/>    </p:column> <p:column> <h:outputText value="#{adminhome.selectedPubblicazioni.ename}" style="float: left;"/>   </p:column>    </p:row>
              <p:row> <p:column> <h:outputText value="Code " style="float: left;margin-left: 30px;color:red;font-size: 18px;font-weight: bold"/>    </p:column> <p:column><h:outputText value="#{adminhome.selectedPubblicazioni.code}" style="float: left;"/>    </p:column>     </p:row>
              <p:row> <p:column>  <h:outputText value="Sample " style="float: left;margin-left: 30px;color:red;font-size: 18px;font-weight: bold"/>    </p:column>  <p:column> <h:outputText value="#{adminhome.selectedPubblicazioni.sample}" style="float: left;"/>    </p:column>    </p:row>

         </p:panelGrid>
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have in your `dialog`?

Comment: this the code for Dialog

Comment: SRy, I updated the code with dialogbox code .